# Overlaying text on a bootstrap carousel image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap carousel with images and I would like to overlay text at the bottom in the center of each carousel image. What's the best way to do this where the text will remain in teh bottom in the center of the image? My image is responsive (img-responsive)
Ex. the image is a profile pic and I would like to show the username in the bottom center area of the image

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mghd060d/)

Here is my code

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="student carousel slide" id="carousel-student-151" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

        <div class="item active" data-studentid="9">
          <a href="/Profile/Public/9" target="_blank">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="data:image/jpg;base64,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">
          </a>
        </div>




      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" role="button" style="visibility: hidden;" href="#carousel-student-151" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" role="button" style="visibility: hidden;" href="#carousel-student-151" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what about adding a 'div' after the image where you put the text and set it's text-align to center; margin-top: -20px; (20 is just an example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and rough way to do it would be something like this:

```html
    <style>
      .rel-img{
        position: relative;
      }
      .overlay-txt{
        position: absolute;
        bottom:0;
        left:12%;
        color:#fff;
       }
    </style>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="student carousel slide" id="carousel-student-151" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">

          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

            <div class="item active" data-studentid="9">
              <a href="/Profile/Public/9" target="_blank">
                <img class="img-responsive rel-img" src="data:image/jpg;base64,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">
<span class="overlay-txt"> My Name Here </span>
              </a>
            </div>




          </div>

          <!-- Controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" role="button" style="visibility: hidden;" href="#carousel-student-151" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" role="button" style="visibility: hidden;" href="#carousel-student-151" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add a text in a div. You can center the accordion items by adding some css properties to your anchors (and don't forget the margin-top of the new added div with the class "text-layer" and the display inline on the image - you may separate the css from the html):

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="student carousel slide" id="carousel-student-151" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

        <div class="item active" data-studentid="9">
          <a href="/Profile/Public/9" target="_blank" style="width: 100%;display: inline-block; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; color: red;">
            <img style="display: inline;" class="img-responsive" src="data:image/jpg;base64,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">
<div class="text-overlay" style="margin-top: -24px">TEXT HIER</div>
          </a>
        </div>




      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" role="button" style="visibility: hidden;" href="#carousel-student-151" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" role="button" style="visibility: hidden;" href="#carousel-student-151" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```